# Best Practices to make my internet facing portal secure

Tags: security, internet-sites

Ok, 
so I finished developing my internet site.
It uses a federation provider to authenticate public user.
Now what I'm concern of, is the site security.
I see that any logged in user can see the _layouts/viewlsts.aspx page.
Even more, they can see data in the lists, and I don't want that to happen.

I searched a lot and find out that users can see even more page I was not aware of.
For example http://site.url/_vti_bin/spdisco.aspx
They can see some webservice sharepoint expose ect

Is there any article with best practices to make my site secure?

Comment: Interesting one, you can lock this down for anonymous users but for authenticated users this is more difficult

Comment: Yes I read about lock down feature, but the problem is there for authenticated users and they can see everything there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waldek is right, you should definitively look into Liam in depth serie.
In the meantime, nothing prevent you from implementing an **http module** like described over there : http://share1point.blogspot.com/2012/10/httpmodule-and-sharepoint-security.html

If you're not able to make distinction from all your authenticated users (eg: public and internal collaborators that will contribute on that site), you should work with extended web applications (or a separate authoring and production environment). The extended application (or isolated environment) will be the only one to receive all your security trimming or custom module like the one suggested.

*Keep in mind that an http module will run for all requests so you definitively want to optimize any procedures over there.*

Answer (score 2):

Liam Cleary (SharePoint MVP) wrote a series of articles on this topic recently. Check out the Security section on his blog for more details: http://blog.helloitsliam.com/Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?CategoryId=11&Name=Security.